# AWS - Cognito - AdminSetUserPassword returns "Operation not found: AdminSetUserPassword"

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I am trying to set a password for a Cognito user that I have already created using the AdminSetUserPassword function, but I keep getting "Operation not found: AdminSetUserPassword" as response.

I have checked the version of CognitoIdentityProvider ('2016-04-18'), which doesn't seem to be the problem. I have also tried to go around it using AdminInitiateAuth and AdminRespondToAuthChallenge, but the problem with the InitiateAuth function is that I get no 'Session' in response! 
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```php
                    $args = [
                        'credentials' => *CREDENTIALS*,
                        'region' => 'eu-central-1',
                        'version' => 'latest',
                        'app_client_id' => *CLIENT_ID*,
                        'user_pool_id' => *USER_POOL_ID*,
                      ];

                      $client = new CognitoIdentityProviderClient($args);

                      try {

                        $response = $client->adminSetUserPassword([
                          "Password" => $new_password,
                          "Permanent" => true,
                          "Username" => *USER_USERNAME*,
                          "UserPoolId" => *USER_POOL_ID*
                        ]);
                        return true;

                      } catch (Exception $e) {
                        return false;
                      }
```

Comment: Did you install the package using Composer? If so, what do you get under `versions` when you run `composer info aws/aws-sdk-php`?

Comment: @Delena Malan I get 3.68.1 under versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AdminSetUserPassword` was only added to the `aws/aws-sdk-php` package in version [3.93.3](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#3933---2019-05-03). You can update your version of the package with `composer require aws/aws-sdk-php:">3.93.3"`.

Comment: Thank you! It's working just fine after the update!

Comment: No problem @S.P.S. ! You can mark the answer as [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it answered your question. :)